# how to avoid the transfer of the outside of a node inside

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-shape, multipart-node

How to avoid that the styles of a node style pass in a schema included in the node

thus on the ECM below, the node of right becomes green and is cut in 2 and that of left does not change of color but is cut off

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{rougelarge/.style={fill=red!20,minimum width=15em,minimum height=4em,text width=15em,draw}}

\newcommand{\nodeUn}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rougelarge](aa){texte sur plusieurs lignes\\texte sur plusieurs lignes};
\node[right=5em of aa,draw](bb){texte};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,fill=green]{texte sur plusieurs lignes
\nodepart{two}
\nodeUn
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should try to avoid nesting Ti*k*Z pictures.

Comment: @marmot, can you explain?

Comment: You should avoid nesting Ti*k*Z pictures. Nesting is not supported. If it works, that's an unfortunate coincidence. (Unfortunate because it will likely break unexpectedly later.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have been told long time ago, I never used a `tikzpicture` nested in another one. Consider to change your approach.

In this case, one way is to define completely the style of each node as you it looks like ant that will prevent the ineherit interraction problem:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}


\tikzset{
    rouge large/.style={%
        fill=red!20,
        minimum width=15em,
        minimum height=4em,
        text width=15em,
        draw,
        rectangle},
    blanc etroit/.style={%
        draw,
        fill=white,
        rectangle},
    }

\newcommand{\nodeUn}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[rouge large] (aa)
        {texte sur plusieurs lignes\\texte sur plusieurs lignes};
    \node[right=5em of aa, blanc etroit] (bb) {texte};
\end{tikzpicture}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,fill=green]
                    {texte sur plusieurs lignes
\nodepart{two}
\nodeUn
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\nodeUn
\end{document}
```

Comment: This still nests `tikzpicture`s and this is expected to break. Even if it seems to work, it is going to come unstuck sooner or later - usually sooner, unless later would be less convenient, in which case, later.

Answer (score 3):

You put a Ti*k*Z picture (stored in the definition of `\nodeUn`) into the node of another Ti*k*Z picture. This very often leads to complications. And there is really no need for that.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, positioning,backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{rougelarge/.style={fill=red!20,minimum width=15em,minimum height=4em,text width=15em,draw}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rougelarge](aa){texte sur plusieurs lignes\\texte sur plusieurs lignes};
\node[right=5em of aa,draw](bb){texte};
\path(aa.west)--(bb.east) node[midway,above=1cm](cc){texte sur plusieurs lignes};
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\node [fit=(aa) (bb) (cc),fill=green,rectangle]{};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**UPDATE**: Of course, you could just switch the option off.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{rougelarge/.style={fill=red!20,minimum width=15em,minimum height=4em,text width=15em,draw}}

\newcommand{\nodeUn}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[rectangle split parts=1]
\node[rougelarge](aa){texte sur plusieurs lignes\\texte sur plusieurs lignes};
\node[right=5em of aa,draw](bb){texte};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,fill=green]{texte sur plusieurs lignes
\nodepart{two}
\nodeUn
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I do *not* recommend going this way. It is foreseeable that it will backfire.

Comment: Non, I don't want a fit node.  is there a command that resets styles to default styles?

Comment: @rpapa Not that I know. All I know is that nesting Ti*k*Z pictures can have undesired consequences, i.e. lead to a result that cannot be controlled. Of course, there are ways to retrieve the Ti*k*Z keys (e.g. using `\pgfkeysvalueof`), i.e. your "default values", but I strongly recommend not to go this way. In this case, you'd have to store these values in some macros and then set them in the inner node. What a mess!

Comment: @rpapa And even with the mess, it won't work properly.